# Correct way of internationalizing links

Tags: seo, html5, internationalization

I am interested in a correct way to show search engine that the link is a translation of some content to another language.

For example: you have some article written in German. So this is original post, but this post was also translated into English, Japanese and French. How should I semantically format these links?

Looking at wikipedia, I see that they are doing it with `<a href="..." title="..." lang="fr" hreflang="fr">Français</a>`. Also I assume that Wiki is doing this in the right way, but I want to know for sure is this the correct way? Also I do not see there how should I specify that German is the original article and everything else is a translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5, the [`alternate` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/links.html#rel-alternate) should be used.

It gets a special meaning when used in combination with the `hreflang` attribute:

> If the `alternate` keyword is used with the `hreflang` attribute, and that attribute's value differs from the root element's language, it indicates that the referenced document is a translation.

So a link to the French translation could look like:

```html
<a href="…" rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" lang="fr">Français</a>
```

HTML5 doesn’t offer a way to denote which of the documents is the original one.

Wikipedia isn’t using the `alternate` link type because the pages in other languages are not (necessarily) translations. They are about the same topic, but may contain totally different content.