# Where do I get a list of attribute 'lang' values - what standard covers this, for SEO optimization?

Tags: html5, language, lang-attribute

I'm working on a website that I need to optimize for multiple-languages. I want to provide support in 3-4 languages, 'en', 'de', 'cn' - the trouble is, I'm not sure what Saudi-Arabia and the gulf countries use.

Is there **an authoritative document that lists out the mappings between nationstate => 'lang-value'**? Where can I find such a document? What web standard covers this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to use HTML5, you should consult the only document that matters, the HTML5 specification:

1. The HTML5 spec is http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/.
2. Search for "lang", and you’ll find the section [The `lang` and `xml:lang` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes).
3. There it defines:

   > Its value must be a valid BCP 47 language tag, or the empty string.
4. "BCP47" is linked in the references: [Tags for Identifying Languages; Matching of Language Tags](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt). A more accessible version of this document (HTML instead of plain text) is https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47.
5. There it says that all values are registered in the *Language Subtag Registry* at iana.org, which would be https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry.
6. Search for the language you are interested in.

   The block has to be of type "language", and the language code (which can be used as value for `lang`) is listed as "Subtag".

   Make sure that you don’t use a value of type "region". Saudi Arabia, for example, has the region subtag `SA`, while the language Sanskrit has the language subtag `sa`.

As explained in BCP 47, you can add a [region](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47#section-2.2.4) to a language. You could, for example, use `lang="en-SA"`, which could mean something like "English as spoken/written in Saudi Arabia", or "English for users in Saudi Arabia".

#### Related links

- Wikipedia: [IETF language tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag)
- W3C: [Choosing a Language Tag](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-language-tags)
- W3C: [Language tags in HTML and XML](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/Overview.en.php)

Comment: Following this, you’ll see that there is no language subtag `cn` defined.

Answer (score 1):

The spec www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1 says that language codes come from RFC1766 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1766.txt, which says:

> The following registrations are predefined:
>
> In the primary language tag:
>
> - All 2-letter tags are interpreted according to ISO standard
>          639, "Code for the representation of names of languages" [ISO
>          639].
> - The value "i" is reserved for IANA-defined registrations
> - The value "x" is reserved for private use. Subtags of "x"
>          will not be registered by the IANA.
> - Other values cannot be assigned except by updating this
>          standard.

wikipedia/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes
--SLaks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497213/where-do-i-get-a-list-of-attribute-lang-values-what-standard-covers-this-fo