# Is it for SEO okay to mix the subfolder structure between /lang/ & /lang-country/?

Tags: url, local-seo, internationalization, multilingual, geotargeting

We are currently maintaining country folders like

```
www.example.net/de/
www.example.net/fr/
```

Now we are thinking about Swiss with 3 languages (it, de, fr). I think it's bad to change all the current directories. Is it okay to only add the region if necessary? For example:

```
www.example.net/de/ = German speaking, not Swiss
www.example.net/fr/
www.example.net/it/
www.example.net/de-CH/ = German speaking, Swiss only
www.example.net/it-CH/
www.example.net/fr-CH/
```

So: Is it for SEO okay to mix the subfolder structure between `/lang/` & `/lang-country/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fine.

It probably doesn’t affect SEO. Consumers would have no reason to parse the URL path segment if they could just parse the [`rel`-`alternate`+`hreflang` markup](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/61357/17633) instead, which is typically easier and more reliable. Any way, even if the URL path segment is used by some consumers, both types are [valid language tags](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/74080/17633) after all.

For what it’s worth, Mozilla does this for their Firefox add-on site, too:

- `es`: https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/noscript/
- `de`: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/noscript/
- `en-GB`: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/noscript/
- `en-US`: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/
- ([`en`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/noscript/) and unknown values redirect to `en-US`)
- ([`de-DE`](https://addons.mozilla.org/de-DE/firefox/addon/noscript/)/[`de-CH`](https://addons.mozilla.org/de-CH/firefox/addon/noscript/) redirect to `de`)