# How can I use dual language metadata?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, multilingual

I have an online newspaper website. The content is fully in the Bangla language. The language of the website is Bangla but visitors are searching in search engines (Google, Yahoo & Bing) in English and coming to my site.

I need to know know how to use metadata (`title`, `meta`-`description`, and `meta`-`keywords`) in both the Bangla and the English language for SEO purposes.

I also need to know whether using multiple languages in the metadata is harmful regarding SEO.

Comment: What are people searching for "in English" that is able to drive a visitor to your site, when your site is "fully in the Bangla language"? That doesn't seem possible?

Answer (score 3):

So you have a page with content (in the `body`) in one language, and you want to provide the metadata (in the `head`) in multiple languages.

#### HTML

In general this is easily possible by providing corresponding `lang` attributes (see an [example with multiple `meta`-`keywords` in different languages](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/74082/17633)), but it doesn’t work in two cases:

- You can only have one [`title`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/document-metadata.html#the-title-element) element.

  > There must be no more than one `title` element per document.
- You can only have one `meta`-[`description`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/document-metadata.html#description) element.¹

  > There must not be more than one `meta` element with its `name` attribute set to the value `description` per document.

Everything else that could be interesting for translation is allowed, I think.

#### SEO

Doing it for SEO purposes probably doesn’t make much sense, as search engine likely have no interest in showing metadata in one language if the content is in another language.

(Also note that most metadata is ignored by search engines in the first place, for example `meta`-`keywords`.)

It shouldn’t harm SEO as long as you don’t deceive with the translations, and as long as you use the `lang` attribute to convey in which language the metadata is.

However, it could be problematic for search engines that don’t notice the `lang` value difference (they might end up using metadata in the wrong language), but I don’t know of any.

---

¹ I [proposed](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/553) to allow multiple `meta`-`description` elements if they have different `lang` values, but it hasn’t been decided yet.