# Will Google ranking my images for two languages if I put alt attribute text in both languages?

Tags: seo, multilingual, alt-attribute

If I have 10 photos, is it practical to make English `alt` attribute for 5 of them and Arabic `alt` attribute for the other 5 images? In a SEO point of view.

Things to know about my site:

1. Hand-coded in HTML & CSS, so no CMS or server-side languages.
2. Main audience are Arabs, buttons in Arabic, no English text on site.
3. Main content on my site is images (wallpapers).

Will Google be able to direct searches in both languages to my site?

Comment: I removed the additional question about `meta`-`description`. You’ll find that it’s [not possible to have multiple `meta`-`description` elements on the same page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/108392/17633).

Comment: If you want to rank in two countries you should duplicate the site on different URLs and put the text for the other language there.   See [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Comment: Thank you for the input, it seems that there is no one way of doing it. Since the site is intended for Arabic world I will tend to keep it that way without English `alt` tags for best results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google will probably focus on tags **[hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)**. You say: "Main audience are Arabs". This means that organic traffic from Arab speaking users is possible. The language of the contents of the **alt** attributes is intended for the same language that is used in the main content of webpage. In addition, the search engines get information for the **[Long Tail](http://searchengineland.com/long-tail-content-for-seo-2013-beyond-167020)** from these attributes. It is also useful to apply for images the attribute **title**. Therefore, *I do not recommend that you apply the content to a attributes of picture in English to the webpage with the main content in Arabic*. This can confuse search engines and damage your website - this is my opinion.

Comment: "This can confuse search engines and damage your website." do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @Steve 1 This is my guess.

Comment: then you ought to say so, not make it sound authoritative.

Comment: Thank you for the input, it seems that there is no one way of doing it. Since the site is intended for Arabic world I will tend to keep it that way without English `alt` tags for best results.